# Sour cream peach pecan pie

Tags: substitutions, pie, peaches

In this recipe it says to use 2 tablespoons of peach preserves what can I use in place of the preserve?   My supermarket does not have it.

Comment: Pauline, welcome! Could you please post the whole recipe, that makes it easier to suggest suitable replacements.

Answer (score 3):

'Preserve' suggests jam - peach jam would be my substitution, at 2tbsp the purpose is most likely to accentuate the peach flavour and potentially add to consistency. Hard to know without recipe context.